# What are the consequences of eating a myconid?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, food-and-drink, out-of-the-abyss

I'm a DM of an Out of the Abyss (OOTA) campaign where the party is considering eating Stool, the myconid from the prison. Considering the whole "don't eat mushrooms you find in the woods" thing we've all been told, I felt it would be a good idea to give some kind of consequence.

Is there any information on the possible consequences for eating myconids? Is this described somewhere in OOTA, or perhaps in another game book with more information on myconids, or more general information on these kinds of effects?

A good-subjective answer could also be based on game-tested experience using house rules for these kinds of effects in 5e also.

Comment: Why can't this just be a DM call? There's literally thousands of different types of mushrooms and every single one of them you can eat; quite a few can only be eaten once.

Comment: It is a DM call. I'm looking for educated recommendations until I find one I like.

Comment: @CollinB then this is an opinion based question and better suited for a forum.

Comment: Are you looking for "treat them like evil scum" as part of these answers? Eating a sentient creature isn't great behaviour

Comment: @CollinB This was closed as opinion-based. I edited to refocus the question on existing game material and the possibility of played/tested house rules in the hopes that this would help the question flourish here. Please feel free to roll back the edit if I misrepresented what you want.

Comment: This question has received a pretty major edit from the version posted by the OP. Given they have already rolled back one similar edit I am going to go ahead and close this until we get confirmation that this is actually the question they want asked.

Comment: @CollinB I've closed this question until you confirm that the edits are still asking what you want. If you are happy with them tag a mod in a comment or flag for reopening and we'll do that for you. Otherwise rollback or [edit] the question further to suit your question and the community can decide if it is suitable for our site. Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

### Eating a Myconid Induces Plot-Relevant Side Effects

The consequences should depend on the narrative purpose of punishing the players.

In your question, you mention a kind of survivalism: the players know (or should know!) not to eat mushrooms, because they may be poisonious. From that I understand your goal is to reward players for demonstrating keen survival skills and not engaging in self-harmful behavior (like eating unidentified mushrooms). In this vein, the consequences from eating a mushroom vary from getting a healthy dose of micro-nutrients to near-instant death.

However, you may have other goals which are worth considering. If this is a part of a story arc regarding the party murdering a fellow prisoner, perhaps you want a consequence that reinforces this. Maybe the mushroom makes them sick for several hours or days, long enough for the authorities to discover the players are murderers.

You don't really need to learn a lot about myconids to craft this kind of thing. Focus on what *you* need as a DM to improve your story. Then, figure out what kind of consequence you need to make that happen.

### Use the Myconids' Spores as Guidance

The *Monster Manual* describes Myconids beginning on page 230. In particular, the text indicates that myconid spores have hallucinogenic properties. This is represented as the *Hallucination Spores* action of the Myconid Sovereign which both poisons and incapicitates the target. Additionally, the *Pacifying Spores* action of the adult myconid can stun people.

Both of these provide some in-game guidance for possible results, though they aren't specifically related to eating them.